# Set String.Format at runtime

Tags: c#

I have an XML File that I want to allow the end user to set the format of a string.

ex:

```
<Viewdata>
<Format>{0} - {1}</Format>
<Parm>Name(property of obj being formatted)</Parm>
<Parm>Phone</Parm>
</Viewdata>
```

So at runtime I would somehow convert that to a `String.Format("{0} - {1}", usr.Name, usr.Phone);`

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'd imagine it may be possible with reflection but this sounds like an XY question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. Format strings are just that, strings.

```
 string fmt = "{0} - {1}";    // get this from your XML somehow
 string name = "Chris";
 string phone = "1234567";

 string name_with_phone = String.Format(fmt, name, phone);
```

Just be careful with it, because your end user might be able to disrupt the program. Do not forget to [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

Comment: Name and Phone appear to be a property of an object so don't think this will work ( was my first thought too)

Comment: @Sayse: still, you can do it in the "user" class. Or just call `String.Format(fmt, usr.Name, usr.Phone)`.

Comment: Yeah but I'd imagine something more generic is needed (where the field isn't known)

Comment: Correct. It will always be of type(User) but I want the end user to set the format and what properties of the obj will be used during the String.Format();

Comment: @Chris. I get it now. I wouldn't implement in this way though, as you would expose your class to an end user. I'd make some kind of format string like `{name} - {phone}` and document which properties you'll accept. Then use string replacement to create the format string. That would also protect you from the user doing stuff like `{0:-10000000000000000000000000}`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Yes I thought about it this way at first and was hoping there was a better way. Still might have to go this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other posters who say **you probably shouldn't be doing this** but that doesn't mean we can't have fun with this interesting question.  So first of all, this solution is *half-baked/rough* but it's a good start if someone wanted to build it out.

I wrote it in LinqPad which I love so `Dump()` can be replaced with console writelines.

```
void Main()
{
    XElement root = XElement.Parse(
@"<Viewdata>
    <Format>{0} | {1}</Format>
    <Parm>Name</Parm>
    <Parm>Phone</Parm>
</Viewdata>");

    var formatter = root.Descendants("Format").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    var parms = root.Descendants("Parm").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

    Person person = new Person { Name = "Jack", Phone = "(123)456-7890" };

    string formatted = MagicFormatter<Person>(person, formatter, parms);
    formatted.Dump();
/// OUTPUT ///
/// Jack | (123)456-7890
}

public string MagicFormatter<T>(T theobj, string formatter, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < propertyNames.Length; index++)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyNames[index]);
        propertyNames[index] = (string)property.GetValue(theobj);
    }

    return string.Format(formatter, propertyNames);
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse (
@"<Viewdata>
<Format>{0} - {1}</Format>
<Parm>damith</Parm>
<Parm>071444444</Parm>
</Viewdata>");


var format =root.Descendants("Format").FirstOrDefault().Value;

var result = string.Format(format, root.Descendants("Parm")
                                     .Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: He wants the params array to be called on an object like user

Answer (score 0):

What about specify your format string with parameter names:

```
<Viewdata>
<Format>{Name} - {Phone}</Format>
</Viewdata>
```

Then with something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/622309/Extended-string-Format

you can do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes but it depends on the variety of your formatting options how difficult it is going to be.

If you have some formatting strings that accept 5 parameter and some other that accept only 3 that you need to take that into account.

I’d go with parsing XML for params and storing these into array of objects to pass to String.Format function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) and make entire format command editable:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Phone;

    public Person(string n, string p)
    {
        Name = n;
        Phone = p;
    }
}

static void TestDynamicLinq()
{
    foreach (var x in new Person[] { new Person("Joe", "123") }.AsQueryable().Select("string.Format(\"{0} - {1}\", it.Name, it.Phone)"))
        Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```